# the date response in API difference 1 day with the real data in Laravel API

Tags: laravel

i have a data that has 2 columns which named `tanggal_mulai` and `tanggal_selesai`.
the date of tanggal_mulai and tanggal_selesai is from user setting.
user can setting the `dates of tanggal_mulai and tanggal_selesai` from API.

the case is, when user set the dates of tanggal_mulai and tanggal_selesai, it saved with the right dates.

> but when we get the data from API, the date of `tanggal_mulai and tanggal_selesai` change to 1 day before the dates. if the data is 10
> Feb 2023, it show 09 Feb 2023.

data from web :

[image]

data from api :

[image]

here is the script to get data from API :

```
$auth = Auth::user();
        $workingPermit = Izin::where('user_id', $auth->id)->where('finish', 1)->latest()->with(['tenant_team', 'item', 'user', 'izinFile'])->first();
        if ($workingPermit) {
            $workingPermit['first_checkin'] = Checkin::where('izin_id', $workingPermit->id)->first();
            $workingPermit['last_checkout'] = Checkin::where('izin_id', $workingPermit->id)->where('goout', 1)->latest()->first();
    }
```

thank youu

Comment: check your timezone of pc and  ```timezone``` of ```config/app.php``` . same?

Comment: @bluestar0505 the timezone is set to Asia/Jakarta. and the user is from Jakarta

Comment: and then check current time of your web server.

Comment: @bluestar0505 the current time of server is difference any hours

Comment: if you run ```date``` command on console, you can check timezone of server.

Comment: $bluestar i have fixed the date of the webserver. and it still give difference 1 day when get the API

Comment: at last you have check timezone of config file of ```httpd```or ```ngnix```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251568/discussion-between-bluestar0505-and-richard-kyle).

Comment: @bluestar505 hi, thank you. i have found the problem. this is happen because i set the tanggal_mulai and tanggal_selesai in models dates. i remove it, and it come to config timezone